# POST request to PHP REST API works only on Postman

Tags: php, rest, api, curl, post

I'm trying to create and access my first Rest API and I'm getting trouble with the **POST** requests. If I test my API on **Postman**, it's working just fine. I can read, delete, etc..

But now I wanna send the data of a **html form** using PHP to my API to create a new record on the database. I'm using only **PHP** and **Mysql** for the project. And I tried to use **CURL** and **file_gets_content**, no success.

What happens is that the array that the API receives is **always empty**. I'm debugging   every step right before the call and the array is not empty, so I imagine that there is something wrong with the call itself.

Here is the part of my **create.php** that receives the data on my API:

```
<?php  
//configuracao de headers
// Headers
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

include_once('../../config/Banco.php');
include_once('../../models/Curso.php');

$banco = new Banco();
$conexao = $banco->conecta();

$curso = new Curso($conexao);

//pega o q foi submetido
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

if (empty($data->id_sala)){
    echo json_encode(array('mensagem'=>'Preencha o id_sala'));
    die();
}
```

And this is the part of a function that I use to call the create method of my API:

```
function criar_curso($nome, $id_professor, $id_sala, $horario_inicio, $horario_fim){

    $url = "http://localhost/desafio-fullstack/api/curso/create.php";

    // Parametros da requisição
    $data = http_build_query(array(
        'nome' => $nome,
        'id_professor' => $id_professor,
        'id_sala' => $id_sala,
        'horario_inicio' => $horario_inicio,
        'horario_fim' => $horario_fim
    ));

    $context = stream_context_create(array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => 'POST',                    
            'header' => "Connection: close\r\n".
            "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n".
            "Content-Length: ".strlen($data)."\r\n",
            'content' => $data                               
        )
    ));

    $contents = file_get_contents($url, null, $context);            
    $resposta = json_decode($contents);  //Parser da resposta Json
    var_dump($resposta);
    die('antes do direcionamento dentro do criar curso');
```

Here I keep getting the message inside the **if** that checks if the **$data->id_sala** is empty. But when I send the same data using Postman, it's not empty. For the purpose of this first API, I wanna use only pure PHP. No external libs like **Guzzle** or anything like that. So, can someone give me a little help?

**UPDATE:**
By changing the header on the call to send json format, I was able to send the data correctly to the API:

```
$opcoes = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Content-type: application/json\r\n",
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'content' => json_encode($data)
        )
    );
    $context  = stream_context_create($opcoes);
    $retorno = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You are sending:

> ```
> "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n".
> ```

… but trying to read:

> ```
> json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
> ```

Since you aren't sending JSON, it fails.

Just read the URL encoded data from `$_POST`.

Comment: So, do I need to remove or replace this line on my call: "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n". ?

Comment: @churros — If you want to send JSON then you need to replace that to say you are sending JSON **and** send JSON. You are currently claiming to send URL encoded data **and** sending URL encoded data. My recommendation (the last line of the answer) remains unchanged.

Comment: Ok, I wanna keep the server receiving json. How do I change the call to send this post data as a json object?